Trying to get Google App Script Code to Acknowledge Cells In A Column in Excel to do Individual Math
I've been working on updating an existing code from an Excel sheet used in PTU (pokemon tabletop United), but i am having some struggles.
I got it to do the math in the column but it wouldn't do on an individual cell. I've tried a few different things, trying to change the data range from where it finds the box to do the calculated mathematics, but all I've gotten is to do all the cells in that column repeating what's in the top most box. Not taking the individual numbers in that columns Cells.
function addQuestXP(){
  var maxxp=0;
  var multiplier=1;
  var main_sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trainer");
  if(main_sheet===null){
    Logger.log("No Trainer Sheet found");
    maxxp=20555;
    multiplier=1
  }else{
    var level=main_sheet.getRange(2,7).getValue();
    Logger.log("Trainer level %s",level);
    if(level<6){
      maxxp=109
    }else if(level<11){
      maxxp=459;
      multiplier=1
    }else if(level<16){
      maxxp=1259;
      multiplier=1
    }else if(level<21){
      maxxp=2354;
      multiplier=2
    }else if(level<26){
      maxxp=3849;
      multiplier=2
    }else if(level<31){
      maxxp=6109;
      multiplier=3
    }else if(level<36){
      maxxp=8769;
      multiplier=3
    }else if(level<41){
      maxxp=11909;
      multiplier=4
    }else if(level<46){
      maxxp=16234;
      multiplier=4
    }else{
      maxxp=20555;
      multiplier=5
    }
  }
  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response=ui.prompt("How much trainer xp or base xp? DO NOT ENTER THE AMOUNT OF XP FOR YOUR TIER! THE SCRIPT WILL MULTIPLY FOR TIER AUTOMATICALLY.");
  var xp=parseInt(response.getResponseText());
  for(var i=0;i<3&&isNaN(xp);i++){
    response=ui.prompt("Please enter an actual number");
    xp=parseInt(response.getResponseText())
  }
  if(isNaN(xp)){
    ui.alert("No valid value entered, ending.");
    return
  }
  if(xp<15){
    xp*=5
  }
  xp=Math.floor(xp*multiplier);
  Logger.log("Adding %s xp to cap of %s",xp,maxxp);
  for(var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    var a1=sheets[i].getRange(1,1);
    var curXPCell=sheets[i].getRange(2,11);
    if(a1.getValue()=='Pokereader'&&!isNaN(parseInt(curXPCell.getValue()))){
      Logger.log('%s has %s xp. Adding %s xp for a total of %s',sheets[i].getName(),curXPCell.getValue(),xp,Math.min(curXPCell.getValue()+xp,maxxp));
      curXPCell.setValue(Math.min(curXPCell.getValue()+xp,maxxp))
    }
  }
}

I did write this to show the common error I get, I've done it a few different ways but this is the best example of the code failure.
i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){var a1=sheets[i].getRange(1,1);var curXPCell=sheets[i].getRange(2,11,100,1);if(a1.getValue()=='Pokereader'&&!isNaN(parseInt(curXPCell.getValue()))){Logger.log('%s has %s xp. Adding %s xp for a total of %s',sheets[i].getName(),curXPCell.getValue(),xp,Math.min(curXPCell.getValue()+xp,maxxp));curXPCell.setValue(Math.min(curXPCell.getValue()+xp,maxxp))}}}




Nickname
Level
XP




Red
4
35


Yellow
2
20


Green
1
19


Blue
5
45



here is an example of data, the column I'm hoping to effect is the XP column to get it to multiply the TXP number by the XP multiplier for that level, its able to do it to an individual cell on multiple sheets, but not multiple cells on the same sheet I'm also not to sure what that get value is for or why its in there and I'm sorry for not providing the correct data before hopefully I got it right this time

Welcome to SO! Please format your code properly; clarify your question, specifying expected and current output; and include a markdown table with your sample data (you can use this tool to create one easily).

If my understanding is correct, you have list of names with different levels and XP, which then whenever you are trying to input an XP(integer) in the prompt, it will do the calculations for all of names based on the level criteria (Maxxp), then will update their current XP. Could you please confirm this?

yes thats correct@ELSRY, it usually does this XP math on every sheet that has NICKNAME in the A, 1 box to do the math on an individual cell
i have changed it to go to the sheet ive that has POKEREADER in tha A, 1 Slot
im trying to get it to do it in one sheet down an entire colomn to reduce sheet braking because of the amount of sheets people need to use (people get to over 50+ pokemon on their sheets) by having it all on one page
if it will Help i can prodie a copy of the Excel sheet with the OG and Edited Xp Macro

@ElementsOfYouTube Thank you for your response to ELSRY. But please note that this is NOT a substitute for providing sample data, and an example of a successful outcome.

curXPCell.getValue() what value is this supposed to be?

|Nickname|Level|XP|
|:----|:----|:----|
|Red|4|35|
|Yellow|2|20|
|Green|1|19|
|Blue|5|45|
here is an example of data, the column I'm hoping to effect is the XP column to get it to multiply the TXP number by the XP multiplier for that level, its able to do it to an individual cell on multiple sheets, but not multiple cells on the same sheet
I'm also not to sure what that get value is for or why its in there
and I'm sorry for not providing the correct data before hopefully I got it right this time @Tedinoz

The question should include all the relevant details. Please [edit] the question yourself to include them.

but not multiple cells on the same sheet I'm also not to sure what that get value is for or why its in there I'm sorry, I don't understand how/where the new data fits into your scenario nor the issue of "multiple cells on multiple sheets". And curXPCell.getValue() is becoming an enigma. Would you please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and then edit your question to include all of the information that a user might need to "understand and reproduce the problem".

@ElementsOfYouTube Thanks for providing extra information. I have a few questions to fully understand your post. 1. Does Red, Yellow, Green, Blue have only the same XP gain? meaning is there only one prompt (How much is the trainer xp or base xp?) for the whole sheet? 2. or each of them (Red, Yellow, Green, Blue) will be prompted for how many XP they gain? 3. If the Question 1 is correct, will this be applicable to all of the sheet with the A1 value of POKEREADER wherein it only requires one question of XP to gain each sheet and it would be applicable to every row data.

1 Red Yellow Green And  Blue get the same XP gain from the 1 prompt is the goal, Base XP is based off what level the pokemon is meant to be, trainer level is determined by a value of points earned and get multiplied per level range to get the Xp value
the prompt for TXP earned and this macro multiplys that and places it inside the cells of the pokemon
yes and no, the code currently goes for a single cell on a sheet with POKEREADER in A1 I'm trying to get it to do this action instead of in a cell on each sheet, in multiple cells on the same sheet in an attempt to minimise sheet totals

@ELSRY hopefully this answered your questions

Getting multiple values using getRange and getValues
In order to achieve your goal of getting all the values of the specific range of a sheet and do the calculations. You may need to use the 4 parameters of getRange() and use the getValues() method.
var levels = main_sheet.getRange(2, 7, main_sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

Meanwhile, to do calculations considering all of the levels, you can use a for loop.
for (var row = 0; row < levels.length; row++) {

Here is the full modified script:
function addQuestXP() {
  var maxxp = 0;
  var multiplier = 1;
  var main_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trainer");

  if (main_sheet === null) {
    Logger.log("No Trainer Sheet found");
    maxxp = 20555;
    multiplier = 1;
  }
  else {
    var levels = main_sheet.getRange(2, 7, main_sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.prompt("How much trainer xp or base xp? DO NOT ENTER THE AMOUNT OF XP FOR YOUR TIER! THE SCRIPT WILL MULTIPLY FOR TIER AUTOMATICALLY.");
    var xp = parseInt(response.getResponseText());

    for (var i = 0; i < 3 && isNaN(xp); i++) {
      response = ui.prompt("Please enter an actual number");
      xp = parseInt(response.getResponseText());
    }

    if (isNaN(xp)) {
      ui.alert("No valid value entered, ending.");
      return;
    }

    if (xp < 15) {
      xp *= 5;
    }

    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    for (var row = 0; row < levels.length; row++) {
      var level = levels[row][0];
      if (level < 6) {
        maxxp = 109;
        multiplier = 1;
      } else if (level < 11) {
        maxxp = 459;
        multiplier = 1;
      } else if (level < 16) {
        maxxp = 1259;
        multiplier = 1;
      } else if (level < 21) {
        maxxp = 2354;
        multiplier = 2;
      } else if (level < 26) {
        maxxp = 3849;
        multiplier = 2;
      } else if (level < 31) {
        maxxp = 6109;
        multiplier = 3;
      } else if (level < 36) {
        maxxp = 8769;
        multiplier = 3;
      } else if (level < 41) {
        maxxp = 11909;
        multiplier = 4;
      } else if (level < 46) {
        maxxp = 16234;
        multiplier = 4;
      } else {
        maxxp = 20555;
        multiplier = 5;
      }

      var updatedXP = Math.floor(xp * multiplier);
      Logger.log("Adding %s xp to cap of %s", xp, maxxp);

      for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        var a1 = sheets[i].getRange(1, 1);
        var curXPCell = sheets[i].getRange(row + 2, 11);

        if (a1.getValue() == 'Pokereader' && !isNaN(parseInt(curXPCell.getValue()))) {
          Logger.log('%s has %s xp. Adding %s xp for a total of %s', sheets[i].getName(), curXPCell.getValue(), updatedXP, Math.min(curXPCell.getValue() + updatedXP, maxxp));
          curXPCell.setValue(Math.min(curXPCell.getValue() + updatedXP, maxxp));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Sample Dataset and output:

Execution log:

References:

getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
getValues()
For loop


This answer is based on the OP's comment and how I understand it. Please do not hesitate to leave a comment if there is a modification needed to satisfy the question.

that fixed the problem thank you!!!! got the code to work @ELSRY
